# ¿Como descargar archivos de google cloud en vue.js

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, descarga

Tengo esta parte del codigo hecho en vue.js  que tiene que descargar archivos de mi bucket  mediante un boton el problema que tengo es al momento de generar la url firmada aparece error he intentado de 2 formas si me podrian ayudar pls
`async descargarArchivo() {
const storage = new Storage({
projectId: 'proyecto-prueba-385021',
keyFilename: 'C:\Daniel\desarrollo de software\SISTEMA GENERAL\finance-be\credentials.json'
});

```
  const bucketName = 'prueba-archivo';
  const fileName = 'Reporte/M7ciYVnLOouQEUjrbwS4WmgF7oQuN6A73YgXWwth.mp4';

  const options = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'read',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000 // Expira en 15 minutos
  };

  try {
    console.log(bucketName);
    console.log(fileName);

    // const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);
    // console.log('file:', file);

    const [url] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).getSignedUrl(options);
    console.log(url); // Aquí se imprime el valor de la variable url

    axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: {
        'Origin': window.location.origin
      }
    }).then(response => {

      console.log(url);
      const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const fileLink = document.createElement('a');

      fileLink.href = fileURL;
      fileLink.setAttribute('download', 'video.mp4');
      document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

      fileLink.click();
    });
    this.mensaje = `Archivo descargado: ${fileName}`;
    console.log(this.mensaje);
  } catch (error) {
    this.mensaje = `Error al descargar el archivo: ${error.message}`;
  }
},`en esta forma me sale error  URL firmada: TypeError: url.URL is not a constructor
```

y de esta otra forma

```
async descargarArchivo() {
  const projectId = 'proyecto-prueba-385021';
  const keyFilename = 'C:\\Daniel\\desarrollo de software\\SISTEMA GENERAL\\finance-be\\credentials.json';
  const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const axios = require('axios');
  const fs = require('fs'); // Importar el módulo fs
  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: keyFilename
  });

  const bucketName = 'prueba-archivo';
  const fileName = 'Reporte/M7ciYVnLOouQEUjrbwS4WmgF7oQuN6A73YgXWwth.mp4';
  const options = {
    action: 'read',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000 // Expira en 15 minutos
  };

  try {
    console.log(bucketName)
    console.log(fileName)
    console.log(options)
    const signedUrlResponse = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).getSignedUrl(options);
    console.log(signedUrlResponse)
    const signedUrl = signedUrlResponse[0];

    const response = await axios({
      url: signedUrl,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream'
    });

    const filePath = 'video.mp4';
    const stream = response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath)); // Usar fs.createWriteStream()

    stream.on('finish', () => {
      this.mensaje = `Archivo descargado: ${fileName}`;
      console.log(this.mensaje);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al generar URL firmada:', error);
  }
},
```

me sale el siguiente error   TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function